# How to apply async await to my fucntion agregarEstadoLike()

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to apply async await to the function agregarEstadoLike, because I need its behavior as a synchronous function. Console shows me:

Step 1

Step 2

Step 4

Step 3

But I need the result of agregarEstadoLike() before to arrive to "Step4"

```
post_Controller.getImagesForFeed = async (req, res) => {
//Here, we get POSTS, 3 BY 3
const userFollowing = req.user;
let ActualPage = 1;
actualPage = req.params.page;
if (actualPage && actualPage >= 1) {
    ActualPage = actualPage;
}

//1.- Getting the follower of the user
await Amistad.find({ usuario: userFollowing }, 'seguidor')
    .populate({ path: 'seguidor' })
    .exec((err, seguidores) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Error devolver el seguimiento' });
        }
        if (!seguidores) {
            return res.status(422).send({ message: 'Aún no estas siguiendo a alguien' });
        }
        //2.- Guardando los _id de los seguidores en un arreglo
        var seguidoresClean = [];
        seguidores.forEach((seguidor2) => {
            seguidoresClean.push(seguidor2.seguidor);
        });
        //3.- Searching posts of the follower (seguidoresClean)            
        const optionsOfPagiante = {
            page: ActualPage,
            limit: 2,
            sort: '-fechaCreacion',
            populate: { path: 'usuario', select: { 'contrasena': 0, } }
        }

        console.log("Step 1")
        Post.paginate({ usuario: { $in: seguidoresClean } }, optionsOfPagiante, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Error posts de seguidores' });
            }
            if (result.docs.length === 0) {
                return res.status(402).send({ message: 'Aún no sigues a alguien, no puedes ver publicaciones' });
            }
        //-------------------------------
        //-------------------------------
        // PROBLEM HERE DOWN
        //-------------------------------
        //-------------------------------
            console.log('Step 2');
            //4.- Adding the state "estalike"
            agregarEstadoLike(userFollowing._id, result); // Step 3
            console.log('Step 4');
            return res.status(200).send(result);
        });
    })
```

};

The function agregarEstadosLikes is:

```
async function agregarEstadoLike(userId, posts) {
//1.- Getting the ids of the 4 posts that arrived and stor them in an array
const newPosts = posts.docs;
const postsIds = newPosts.map(newPost => newPost._id);
console.log(postsIds);
//2.- Search if there is like between the post of the array and the user
return await Like.find({
    usuario: userId,
    post: { $in: postsIds }
}).then((likes) => {
    const idDeLosPostsConLike = likes.map(like => like.post);
    newPosts.forEach(newPost => {
        // 3.- Checking if the user push "like" to the post
        if (idDeLosPostsConLike.some(id => id.equals(newPost._id))) {
            newPost.estaLike = true;
            console.log('Step3', newPost.estaLike);
        }
    });
    return newPosts;
});
```

}

I tried different ways but I can´t.

Comment: you'll need to `await` it - but you'll need to change the callback function to `Post.paginate` into `async (err, result) =>`

Comment: it was something so simple, thaks